# PDF to download, not link to view/download

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so when you click "download here" a pdf file will download to the user's desktop. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: whats your setup? PHP? Apache? There's a number of options depending on this

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`Content-Disposition`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields) header.

But, please: Only do this if it is *really* necessary for the user to download the PDF and not open it (so that it’s just an aid for the user that he does not have to explicitly select “save file”). Don’t use it to force the user to download it although he just wants to view it.

Comment: Nice. Never used that header.

Answer (score 3):

code for a.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf')
echo file_get_contents("file.pdf");
?>
```

link it in web:

```
 <a href="a.php">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue and only few people know there's a simple HTML 5 solution:

```
<a href="./directory/yourfile.pdf" download="newfilename">Download the pdf</a>
```

Where `newfilename` is the suggested filename for the user to save the file. Or it will default to the filename on the serverside if you leave it empty, like this:

```
<a href="./directory/yourfile.pdf" download>Download the pdf</a>
```

Compatibility: I tested this on Firefox 21 and Iron, both worked fine. It might not work on HTML5-incompatible or outdated browsers. The only browser I tested that didn't force download is IE...

Comment: This only work for same-origin URLs (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is to control browser behavior - this is not simple.

The best bet you have it to point the link to what seems like a web page (i.e. `download.php?file=1`) and once the browser notices it's binary data, it will ask the user what it wants to do with it. This method will most likely get the job done.

But note that this behavior cannot be guaranteed, and is highly-dependent on browser configuration.

Comment: Since this method is not recommended how should I present the pdf? Should I copy and paste it onto the page? I've seen pdfs in web browsers, but I don't know how they do it. Also I'm just a beginner in web design. I have no clue what binary data is, sorry.

Sincerely,

Caleb

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a  `<meta>` tag for that. I *think* it's called 'nosave'. Don't go seaching the WWW for that though - I was searching and couldn't find it.